# Can I debug my native code in Android studio 1.5.1 without experimental gradle plugin?

Tags: android, c++, debugging, java-native-interface, native

Is there a way to debug native code using the newest gradle (2.8, 2.10 or 2.12)? I cannot use the experimental plugin (that is supposed to support debugging) because I need to load OpenCV libraries, so I disabled automatic ndk-build call with auto-generated Android.mk and do it manually.
I have included this to my app's build.gradle,

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable = true
            jniDebuggable = true
        }
    }
```

and at the Run->Edit configurations the app-native icon appears without the X now. But still it doesn't break at the breakpoints of the .cpp file in the jni folder.
 Is there any way to achieve it? I'd appreciate any help or suggestion, cause I'm in a dire need here... Thanks!